# pyodbc installation issues on Mac

Tags: python, sql, macos, pyodbc

I'm trying to install pyodbc on my mac because I want to connect to a sql server and I have been going through a lot of forum to get it to work. Everything has been install except the pyodbc (I've tried pip,homebrew, easy_istall and even tried to install using the source code but nothing worked) and it's giving me the following error:

---

```
(hhl)OSFOLA-034901:bin henry.humadi$ easy_install pyodbc
Searching for pyodbc
Reading https://pypi.python.org/simple/pyodbc/
Reading http://code.google.com/p/pyodbc
Reading http://code.google.com/p/pyodbc/downloads/list
Best match: pyodbc 3.0.7
Downloading http://pyodbc.googlecode.com/files/pyodbc-3.0.7.zip
Processing pyodbc-3.0.7.zip
Writing /var/folders/w4/h0nc35117x1c0psqpsm4vvlnhk02nh/T/easy_install-AFM6yU/pyodbc-3.0.7/setup.cfg
Running pyodbc-3.0.7/setup.py -q bdist_egg --dist-dir /var/folders/w4/h0nc35117x1c0psqpsm4vvlnhk02nh/T/easy_install-AFM6yU/pyodbc-3.0.7/egg-dist-tmp-G6Yp3F
warning: no files found matching 'tests/*'
clang: error: unknown argument: '-mno-fused-madd' [-Wunused-command-line-argument-hard-error-in-future]
clang: note: this will be a hard error (cannot be downgraded to a warning) in the future
error: Setup script exited with error: command 'cc' failed with exit status 1
```

---

Can anyone please decipher this error message for me. I read somewhere it has to do with Xcode 5.1 but I still don't understand it.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: If you continue to have problems with pyodbc then you might consider trying [pypyodbc](https://code.google.com/p/pypyodbc/) instead. It has resolved a number of issues with pyodbc for Mac users in the past.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Xcode 5 caused clang to throw a fatal error when it encountered a command line flag, which broke a lot of things.

Run the command like this and it should work:
`ARCHFLAGS=-Wno-error=unused-command-line-argument-hard-error-in-future easy_install pyodbc`

Comment: Is it possible to do it from the source code? I'm trying to introduce a patch so pyodbc can talk to unixODBC instead iODBC. I'm trying to follow this link:

https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/django-users/qE02V2MCkck/LCO6LHOzAX8J

Comment: @Henry80s, when you say source code, do you mean a build script/make file?

Comment: I figured it out, I wanted to do the same thing above but with python install setup.py. It turned out that I can do the exact same thing. Sorry to waste your time.